# Console warning " no activity specified getting the launcher activity "

Tags: android, console, manifest

```
here is my manifest file of my sample application .when ever I run my project , I got warning in console "**no activity specified getting the launcher activity**" . I follow all the steps of solution regarding this but still the problem occur .
```

however this doesn't appear to effect the app at all, it still starts up fine and closes fine after use etc, it does however pull focus to the console which is annoying for debugging.
    Manifest file :

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Pick_Date_Time" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

in this file I set the

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

As per many solution suggest.

Still have problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: here is the full code of my manifest file : http://paste.org/70964

Comment: Name_of_Activity1 is your launcher activity and others are subsequent. You can add other activities in any order after launcher activity.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

You need to give the relative or full path of you activity in the name like:

//added dot to give relative name

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
```

or

//Full path

```
<activity android:name="com.android.MainActivity" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Replace your `mainfest` file with this and replace `YourPackageName` with your package name.

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
      <activity android:name="YourPackageName.Pick_Date_Time" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="YourPackageName.AnotherActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: its compulsory that we have only one Activity tag like <activity
            android:name=".Demo12Activity" > actually i have 3 Activity tag that I have to modify as per you suggest ? so which one will be modify ?

Comment: All of three because activity refer with their package name so mention full path and activity name.

Comment: @Angle : still getting the same issue . :-/

Comment: i post the link below my question in comments .

Comment: check that link I made some changes.

Comment: where did u change in code ?? i cant catch clearly .plz specify that

Answer (score 1):

See this sample code and make changes in your manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your_package_name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </uses-permission>
    //Add more permissions according to your requirement

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="false">
        <activity
            android:name="your_package_name.Name_of_Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Name_of_Activity2">
        </activity>
         </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Name_of_Activity3">
        </activity>    

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Name_of_Activity4">
        </activity>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Name_of_Activity5">
        </activity>

         </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Name_of_Activity6">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```